# Approach to the irregular weight training

Tags: weightlifting, workout, training, gym

I know that the key to success in weight training is consistency and regime: never skipping a workout and so on. I manage to be consistent sometimes, sometimes not (and these tend to be periods of 4-6 months). When the real life breaks the balance and consistency, I don't manage to be get to the gym for 1.5 hours 3 times a week, sometimes it's two times a week with 5 day interval, sometimes skipping a week and so on.

While it's obvious that any really good results can't be produced during such periods, what could be the best approach to the training in such circumstances? Focusing on few base movements like squat and press and doing all of them each time? Or trying to do as much different exercises as possible for less sets? I'm not looking for a definite silver-bullet solution, but what are the options which make sense?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with job, and family likely experiences what you describe, and has the same question. What is the best routines for time available. I think personally basic movement patterns and exercise to counterbalance the repetitive nature of work (long hours of sitting, standing, bad posture etc..) in combination with stretching is the best the non athlete can aim for. A well rounded ability.

There is likely no silver bullet. Train your weakness and maintain your strengths on time crunch weeks. And do more when you have time

Comment: as an addition to answer, there is a browser extension which reminds you to do little *desk exercises* while you sit at your desk in work. https://www.stretchclock.com/download/

Aslo checkout this list : https://www.umsystem.edu/totalrewards/wellness/activity_and_break_apps